# Thin or thick wall for expanding rubber pressure cylinder

Tags: stresses, strength, pressure-vessel, elastic-modulus

If I want to expand a rubber cylinder by a certain internal volume - with all else held constant (type of material, length and radius (without constraining it), etc.) will a thinner or thicker walled cylinder cope with greater volumetric expansion before rupture?

(The thick and thin versions have the same ID, it is the OD which changes in each case.)

Comment: What do you mean by "survive to greater expansion/time (i.e. have a greater fatigue resistance)"? Is that "expansion over time"? But what does that mean? What can resist the highest "speed of expansion"? But that doesn't have anything to do with fatigue resistance, though. Fatigue requires cyclical loading, which you don't give us any information on. Fatigue isn't so much about how fast you go between the maximum and minimum values, but the relative size of those max/min values. Please [edit] your question to clarify it.

Comment: @Wasabi Hi, does that clarify it enough?